# Editing Theme to apply Co-Authors Plus

Tags: plugins, theme-development

I'm trying to implement the [Co-Authors Plus](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/co-authors-plus/) Plugin. It says that you will need to change some PHP in the theme. The documentation [outlines the changes](http://vip.wordpress.com/documentation/incorporate-co-authors-plus-template-tags-into-your-theme/).

I believe I have found where I would need to change it in my theme. In the `post-author-info.php` file:

```
<?php
/**
 * Post Author Info
 *
 * @package WP Journal
 * @subpackage Include
 */
 ?>

<div id="authorinfo" class="columns alpha omega marT30 marB20">
    <a href="<?php the_author_meta('url'); ?>"><?php echo get_avatar( get_the_author_meta('email'), '80' ); ?></a>
    <h5 class="marB10"><?php _e('By', 'contempo'); ?>: <a href="<?php the_author_meta('url'); ?>"><?php the_author(); ?></a></h5>
    <p><?php the_author_meta('description'); ?></p>
        <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

Just adding this line:

```
<?php if ( function_exists( 'coauthors' ) ) { coauthors(); } else { the_author(); } ?>
```

…seems to give me something that I want. Both "Admin" And "Andrew Gable" are displayed.

[image]

But, I'm unsure on how to get it to link correctly, and how to handle photos and multiple Bio's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for something like [this article](http://theitechblog.com/928/display-multiple-authors-author-box-below-article-wordpress/). It's rather comprehensive, but I'll just cover the multiple BIOs and avatars. You'll want to change your HTML code to this instead:

```
<?php $i = new CoAuthorsIterator(); ?>
<?php while( $i->iterate() ) : ?>
<div id="authorinfo" class="columns alpha omega marT30 marB20">
    <a href="<?php the_author_meta('url'); ?>"><?php echo get_avatar( get_the_author_meta('email'), '80' ); ?></a>
    <h5 class="marB10"><?php _e('By', 'contempo'); ?>: <a href="<?php the_author_meta('url'); ?>"><?php the_author(); ?></a></h5>
    <p><?php the_author_meta('description'); ?></p>
        <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Here we interate through the different authors and display an avatar and BIO section for each one. Any content you add between the `while` and `endwhile` statements will be displayed once for each author.

You also may want to replace where it says `By Andrew Gable` in the grey bar above the author box (in your template it probably looks like `<?php the_author_posts_link() ?>`) with `<?php coauthors_posts_links(); ?>`.

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate since it is also asked at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15119535/editing-theme-to-apply-co-authors-plus/19566948

I had a similar issue and resolved it this way:

```
global $post;
$author_id=$post->post_author;
foreach( get_coauthors() as $coauthor ): ?>
  <div class="entry-author co-author">
    <?php echo get_avatar( $coauthor->user_email, '96' ); ?>
    <h3 class="author vcard"><span class="fn"><a href="<?php echo get_author_posts_url( $coauthor->ID, $coauthor->user_nicename ); ?>"><?php echo $coauthor->display_name; ?></a></span></h3>
    <p class="author-bio"><?php echo $coauthor->description; ?></p>
    <div class="clear"></div>
   </div><!-- .entry-author co-author -->
<?php endforeach;
```

Be sure to use that `global $post;`and the `foreach`-loop.

This function will display an author box containing author image/avatar, author name with link to its archive, and the author's bio. You might want to use your own theme's CSS classes though.

The URL [bungeshea](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/19726/bungeshea) posted was helpful.